# Ruby 1.9.2: How to change scope/binding of a block

Tags: ruby, block, ruby-1.9.2

Hi I have something like the folowing:

```
class TrialRequest

  attr_accessor :trial_email

  def initialize(email)
    @trial_email = email
    puts "Trial_email: #{trial_email}"
  end

  def create
    @email = ::Gmail.connect!(gmail_name, gmail_password) do |gmail|
      email = gmail.compose do
        to 'trial@domain.com'
        from trial_email
        subject trial_email
        text_part do
          content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
          body 'Sign me up.'
        end
      end
      #binding.pry
      gmail.deliver!(email)
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that inside the compose block `trial_email` is not defined:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `trial_email' for #<Mail::Message:0x0000000431b830>
```

Is this a Ruby 1.9 issue or a gmail gem issue?

How should I go about making this method 'visible'/within the scope of the compose block?

**Update:**
This is an issue/feature of the gmail gem - ruby 1.9 blocks have changed but not this much! 
In addition to the accepted answer, another workaround is to pass the data in as a method parameter:

```
def create(trial_email)
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a GMail issue to me. Inside the blocks, `self` will be some object from the GMail gem so that you can have `to`, `from`, and similar DSL niceties available. You should be able to put `self.trial_email` into a local variable and then access that inside the blocks:

```
email_address = self.trial_email
@email = ::Gmail.connect!(gmail_name, gmail_password) do |gmail|
  email = gmail.compose do
    to 'trial@domain.com'
    from email_address
    subject email_address
    #...
```

Comment: I got this to work by making create take a param.  which I think has the same effect as what you suggest.  Correct?

Comment: It's not an issue, it's a limitation of `instance_eval`, isn't it?

Comment: @Hedgehog: More or less yes, the parameter takes the place of my `email_address` local variable.

Comment: @KL-7: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @muistooshort, from a block you can reference all local variables of the context where the block was created. But in the OP's example `trial_email` is actually a method of a different object so it's not 'remembered' by a block as part of its context. That's why when this block is passed to other's object `instance_eval` reference to `trial_email` gets lost. But if you replace it with local variable block still can use it as it's a part of block's context now.

Comment: @Kl-7: Hence the suggestion to use `email_address = self.trial_email` to avoid the whole "`self` isn't what you think it is" problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting (as you're entitled to) that the block should preserve the value of self, as it usually does. It looks like the gmail gem is using `instance_exec` here which allows it to change the value of self for the block to an instance of `Mail::Message` (which is why you can call `to` and `from` in that block even though you define no such methods)

While `instance_exec` is handy for producing nice DSLs, it is not without its downsides. Local variable scope isn't affected so you could store either `trial_email` or `self` in a local variable prior to the block and then use that local variable inside the block

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the block you pass to `compose` method is later passed to `Mail.new` and finally to `Message.new` (if I traced the chain correctly) and then this block is evaluated like that [here](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/message.rb#L129):

```
instance_eval(&block)
```

As it's performed inside `initialize` method of a different object (instance of `Message` class) you do not have access to attributes of your `TrialRequest` object.

You can do the same thing without having any troubles like that:

```
email = gmail.compose
email.to = 'trial@domain.com'
email.from = trial_email
email.subject = trial_email

email.text_part do
  content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
  body 'Sign me up.'
end
```